# Is user data encryption required with CosmosDB?

Tags: node.js, encryption, azure-cosmosdb

I have private user data stored in CosmosDB, which has encryption at rest. Does this mean I still need to store encrypted data or is it already encrypted by Cosmos?

If not, what is the recommened npm package to encrypt data. I am looking for one that allows me to decrypt as well, and return the original value and not just true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement and what you mean by "private user data".

As you said, CosmosDB encrypts data at rest and also in transit.
At rest encryption means that if someone somehow gets access to the hard drive where the cosmosdb files are stored he cannot read them.

However that doesn't mean that if he gets the master key he cannot read the documents. At rest encryption is completely transparent to you. If you have a requirement to encrypt "private user data" (whatever that means to you) then you should encrypt it. However if you need to query on them things get way more complicated. If your question is driven by the GDPR regulations, then you don't really have to encrypt anything, as the at rest encryption covers that need.

Comment: I mean user passwords and access tokens, which I would have to query.

Comment: Passwords should be hashed not encrypted. You then hash the input and compare. Also you wouldn't store access tokens. You would validate them based on their authenticity and you could store the revoked ones so they can be rejected.

Comment: Ok. Would crypto-js be something I would hash with, or is that something more like bcrypt (True/false response). Regarding access tokens, if I do not store them, how would I call them for use? Is this worth moving to private conversation?

Comment: Yeah let's take it to a private convo. About access tokens, it really depends on what they are and how you use them so to say you wouldn't store them is a bit of a bold claim indeed.

Comment: I don't have 100 reputation - can you initiate?